# How to update single property in azure table entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-table-storage

Hi i am working on azure table "T1"
and this table have list of entity set

```
Primarykey  RowKey   P1  P2
PP          R1       5   10
PP          R2       6   11
```

now suppose i want to update only P2 property and don't want to touch P1 property 
is this possibly to update single property in azure table entity.
**Remember** i don't want to touch P1 property cos it continuously updating by other function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The operation you would want to perform is [`Merge Entity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179392.aspx). From the REST API documentation:

> The Merge Entity operation updates an existing entity by updating the
>   entity's properties. **This operation does not replace the existing
>   entity, as the Update Entity operation does.**

Here's a sample code that you can use:

```
    static void MergeEntityExample()
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = client.GetTableReference("TableName");
        var entity = new DynamicTableEntity("PartitionKey", "RowKey");
        entity.ETag = "*";
        entity.Properties.Add("P2", new EntityProperty(12));
        var mergeOperation = TableOperation.Merge(entity);
        table.Execute(mergeOperation);
    }
```

The above code will only update "P2" property in the entity and will not touch other properties.